# How to Close JQuery Dialog on clicking a link on it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a link on parent page which opens a dialog which loads a file.asp have form and database result set with hyper links. When click on one hyperlink (JavaScript function in separate .js file), it updates some info to parent page and tried to close the dialog.

I have two problems.
1. When use `$("#myDiv").dialog("close");` from inside a .js

```
function UpdateProdInfo() {
    // some code here to update parent and it works
$("#myDiv").dialog("close"); }
```

it gives initialization error on using close function.
2. Problem in opening second time dialog, still initializing error.

Please let me know how can I do this? Thanks QF

Comment: can you share the complete error message from the console

Comment: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Comment: how are you opening the dialog

Comment: Please look at this link which I asked after this question with all code in detail

Here is the code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491173/hyperlink-on-jquery-dialog-fail-to-close-dialog

Comment: What is the relationship between page 1 and page 2

Comment: Page 1 is master page, page 2 is for looking products and user will select any product, click on its hyperlink and this will go back to master page and populate it in edit box etx. then the dialog will be closed. Page 2 is actually a submit form with more search options to filer the search criteria. Its a separate .asp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is since the `default2.asp` is loaded as a dynamic content to an existing page, it  should not have all html elements like `html`, `body` and `head` etc.

If you remove them and the script and css includes like jquery.js and jqueryui.css and js it works fine

Demo: [Problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/byJbF1u9bNrVnEoRkjQh?p=preview)
Demo: [Solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/dhXgCxId2hzH46KRQEen?p=preview)

Defaut2.asp should be something like

```
This is Default3.asp file
<br><br>

Something
<a href="Javascript:CloseMe();">Close Me</a>

<br><br>
<form ID=Form2 >
  Name: <input type="text" name="Name"><br>
    Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>    

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#Form2').submit(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "Default2.asp", 
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#mydiv').html(result);
                }
            });
        });

        var MyDlg = $( "#mydiv" );

        $(".ui-widget-overlay").click (function () {
            MyDlg.dialog( "close" );
        });
    });

    function CloseMe() {
        $( "#mydiv" ).dialog("close");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, it looks from your demo that it is working, I am going to edit my default2.asp file and will try and will let you know. Atleast this is the first solution closest to my requirements. Thanks again :)

Comment: I checked this and it works fine in Chrome, a lot of thanks to you for this. But unfortunately did not work on IE and my application only works on IE, thats the big problem. Can you please remove this last hurdle in this? I was struggling to solve this since 3 weeks.

Comment: sorry I dont know what fiddle is?

Comment: the demo's in the solution

Comment: no I tried it in IE but it did not show any code, just empty html file

Answer (score 1):

Use the context-parameter:

```
$("#myDiv",parent.document).dialog("close");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
parent.$("#myDiv").dialog("close");
```

because your dialog is defined in the parent page.

Comment: I don't think parent will work since there is no mention of a separate frame

Comment: For some reason I got a distinct impression that dialog shows "file.asp" in an iframe. I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization error `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'` happens when you attempt to close a dialog that hasn't been opened yet.

This could be either

1. **`dialog('close')` is firing before it's been opened,** which you could rule out if you can see the dialog) or
2. **The selector `$('#myDiv')` is not getting the right element somehow.**

I'm guessing it's probably #2. I would try debugging it by doing...

```
function UpdateProdInfo() {
    // some code here to update parent and it works
    console.dir($('#myDiv'));  //Does it return the correct element?
    //$("#myDiv").dialog("close"); 
}
```

...to see if it's selecting the correct element.

Comment: shows this but nothing works,  jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[0]
context: document
selector: "#myDiv"
__proto__: Object[0]

Comment: @qazifarhan Yes, that's exactly what I expected to see. The portion `init[0]` tells me that your selector is not retrieving the element. If it was, that would be `init[1]`, and you could expand that to see the property `0: div#myDiv`. The selector you're using is `#myDiv`, which is supposed to select an element that looks something like: `<div id="myDiv"></div>`. Does the id attribute of your div look exactly like that, and are you using `console.dir($('#myDiv'));`?

Comment: <div id="mydiv"  title="Product Wizard">
</div>


function CloseThis() {
if  ($( this ).is( ".ui-dialog" ) )
{ $('#mydiv').dialog().dialog("close"); }
};

Comment: @qazifarhan - Now that you've posted that code snippet... Hmm. I may need to add this to my answer, and you may want to post this code in your question... There are a couple obvious problems with it. First, `this` in the context of your function is almost certainly going to be `window`. Second, you're calling `.dialog()`, and then immediately calling `.dialog("close")`. That's kind of like calling `.show().hide()`. If you're just trying to close, the first `.dialog()` isn't needed. Also, you're checking to see if it's a dialog `(.is(".ui-dialog"))` -- that shouldn't be necessary.